# Классы в С++. Выделение памяти. Деструкторы

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    char *floor;
    char *phone;
public:
    Person() {
        cout << " ok" <<endl;   
        age = 0;
        phone = new char[9];
        phone = "no phone";
        floor = new char[10];
        floor = "undefined";
        name  = new char[8];
        name  = "no name";        
    }

    Person(const Person &obj) {
        cout << " ob" << endl;
        age = 0;
        phone = new char[*obj.phone];
        phone = "no phone";
        floor = new char[*obj.floor];
        floor = "undefined";
        name  = new char[*obj.name];
        name  = "no name";
    }

    ~Person() {
        cout << " no" << endl;
        if( name != NULL)
            delete name;

        if(floor != NULL)
            delete floor;

        if( phone != NULL)
            delete phone;
    }

    void ename() {
        cout << " Enter new name : ";
        char temp[50];
        gets(temp);
        name = new char[strlen(temp)+1];
        strcpy(name,temp);
        cout<<endl;
    }

    void efloor() {
        cout << " Enter new floor : ";
        char temp[50];
        gets(temp);
        floor = new char[strlen(temp)+1];
        strcpy(floor,temp);
        cout << endl;
    }

    void ephone() {
        cout << " Enter new phone : ";
        char temp[30];
        gets(temp);
        phone = new char[strlen(temp)+1];
        strcpy(phone,temp);
        cout << endl;
    }

    void eage() {
        cout << " Enter new age : ";
        cin >> age;
        cin.ignore(1);
        cout << endl;
    }

    void print();
};

void Person::print(){
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << floor << endl;
    cout << age << endl;
    cout << phone << endl;
}

void add(class Person*&, int&);

void main() {
    int n = 1;
    Person *mas = new Person[n];
    for(;;) { // for 1      
        cout << endl << "SELECT ACTION : " << endl;
        cout << "1 - Edit Person" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Print Person" << endl;
        cout << "Your choice :  ";
        int v;
        cin >> v;
        cin.ignore(1);  
        switch(v) {
        case 1:
            for(;;) { //for 2
                cout << endl << "Click to edit :" << endl;
                cout << "1 - Name" << endl;
                cout << "2 - Floor" << endl;
                cout << "3 - Age" << endl;
                cout << "4 - Phone" << endl;
                cout << "5 - Exit" << endl;
                cout << "Your choice :  ";
                int v1;
                cin >> v1;
                cin.ignore(1);
                cout << endl;   

                switch(v1) { // switch 2
                case 1: 
                    mas[n].ename();                 
                    continue;
                case 2: 
                    mas[n].efloor();
                    continue;
                case 3: 
                    mas[n].eage();
                    continue;
                case 4: 
                    mas[n].ephone();
                    continue;
                case 5: 
                    add(mas,n);
                    break;
                default: 
                    cout << "\a Error, select the correct action!"<<endl;
                    continue;
                } // switch 2                           
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << endl;   
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                mas[i].print();
                cout << endl;
            }   
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\a Error, select the correct action!" << endl;
            break;          
            } // for 2
        }// switch 1    
    }//for 1

    delete[]mas;    
}

void add(Person *&mas,int &n){
    cout << " add" << endl;

    Person *mast = new Person[n+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mast[i] = mas[i];

    n = +1;
    delete[] mas;
    mas = mast;
}
```

Comment: умеете вы задавать вопросы

Comment: какой есть.

Comment: Ошибка в функции add. Или в деструкторе класса.

Comment: Так в чем вопрос та?

Comment: Что неправильно? После функции add вылетает.

Comment: Ещё один ундервуд, пардон -- вундеркинд. Вывалил текст, что с ним происходит, с этим текстом, не понятно. Вопрос: "что неправильно?" Ну на этот вопрос ответить несложно: программа. А если Вы желаете более подробный ответ, то объясните, что это за нетленка? И для затравки, что должны означать вот такие конструкции:

        phone=new char[9];
        phone="no phone";

Конструкция явно бредовая. Деструктор от такого должен шизеть. (Да, кстати, в delete не надо  указывать, что Вы массив освобождаете, а не скаляр?)

Comment: phone=new char[9];
можно и без этого, но так так вроде надежней.
Нужно заполнить динамический массив. Но при выделении новой памяти, происходит ошибка.

Comment: phone="no phone";
    name="no name";
Неверно, так как память, выделенная под "no name" исчезает, после того как выполнится функция в которой они были обьявлены (конструктор). Нужно делать так, как в ename() :
    phone=new char[9];
    strcpy(phone,"no phone");

Comment: @beardog ситуацию описали немного неправильно. Память, выделенная под phone становится "потерянной", т.е. выделенной, но ссылок на неё нет. А память под константу "no phone" никуда не девается, она на странице read-only...

Называется "утечка памяти" -- memory leak.

А вот когда к указателю на константу пытаются применить delete -- тут получается смешнее.

Comment: @sasha777:

     Но при выделении новой памяти, происходит ошибка.

Что, так на экране появляется окно с кнопкой "закрыть" и одним сообщением крупными буквами: "О Ш И Б К А"? Если хотите, чтобы Вам помогли, описывайте ситуацию поконкретней.


А насчёт "так вроде надёжней" надеюсь уже понятно?

Comment: **A few years later...** В этом коде несколько неточностей со скобками.  ) Ошибки не проверял ))

Answer (score 3):

```
phone=new char[*obj.phone];
phone="no phone";
```

как было отмечено выше через strcpy, либо используй std::string

```
if(name!=NULL)
   delete name;
```

проверка не нужна, т.к.  delete NULL - корректное выражение и никаких последствий не будет (другое дело когда у тебя

```
char* p;
delete p;
//или
char *p = new char[n];
delete [] p;
delete [] p;
```

)

```
void ename(){
     cout<<" Enter new name : ";
     char temp[50];
     gets(temp);
     name=new char[strlen(temp)+1];
     strcpy(name,temp);
     cout<<endl;
}
```

происходит утечка памяти, память по старому name не удаляется (а она по умолчанию у тебя выделена в конструкторе)
в аналогичных функциях происходит кстати тоже самое.

```
сase 1:mas[n].ename();
```

тут выход за границы массива, у тебя выделен в памяти n элементов, нумерация от 0 до n-1, по n уже ничего нету

наверняка есть еще какие-то грабли, которых я не заметил

Answer (score 1):

В конструкторе копирования ошибки

```
phone=new char[*obj.phone];
phone="no phone";
```